# Android - How to NOT use some dependencies for a specified flavor?

Tags: android, gradle

For example, There is a dependency `ZZZ`, and 6 flavors `flavor1`, `flavor2`, ... , `flavor6`.

If only want `flavor1` add the dependency, I can use this:

```
dependencies {
    flavor1Implementation `ZZZ`
}
```

But if I want all flavors except `flavor1` to add this dependency, like this:

```
dependencies {
    flavor2Implementation `ZZZ`
    flavor3Implementation `ZZZ`
    flavor4Implementation `ZZZ`
    flavor5Implementation `ZZZ`
    flavor6Implementation `ZZZ`
}
```

It's a disaster when I have many flavors...

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: does the proposed solution work for you?

Answer (score 0):

One option will be to use `variantFilter`, for instance:

```
android {
    productFlavors {
       flavor1 { 

       }
       flavor2 {

       }
       flavor3 {

       }
       ...
    }

    variantFilter { variant ->
        if (!variant.flavors.name.contains("flavor1")) {
            var nameVariant = variant.flavors.name[0]
            getDependencies().add("${nameVariant}Implementation", "ZZZ")
        }
     }
}
```

With `variantFilter` you can loop through each combination between `buildTypes` and `productFlavors`, avoiding to add dependencies on `flavor1` and add the required dependencies programmatically in all the others.

Hope this helps